# Should a Queue implement an Iterable interface?

Tags: java, data-structures, iterable

I recently learned about the Iterable interface when writing my own implementation of a LinkedList. However, this made me question if a previous implementation of a Queue and Stack that are working nicely should implement Iterable as well and why? If yes, could you provide an example of how will you use the iterator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Iterator is useful when you want to iterate over something. That **might** be the case for a queue.

If you look into the standard library, you find an interface `java.util.Queue`. This interface is implemented by the `java.util.AbstractQueue` **which is iterable**. The Queue is also implemented by `java.util.ArrayDeque` **which is also iterable**.

*Useful information:* Deque stands for double ended queue. The ArrayDeque is probably the best implementation of a Queue, also regarding performance.

[java.util.Queue (official documentation)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

Comment: Don't leave out `LinkedList`.

Comment: This was never intended to be complete. I added a link so everyone can look up the derived classes of Queue.